# Using user authentication/sessions with Django and ASIHttpRequest

Tags: ios, django, authentication, asihttprequest, session-cookies

I am trying to make a basic authentication system in iOS that sends a POST to Django and on the Django side authenticates the user and starts a session. Right now I am able to send the user information by passing the values as data in the URL and authenticating it, but how do I retrieve the session data or cookie from the Django response? When I try to store or print out the cookie, it tells me the array is empty. I have tried both request.requestCookies and request.responseCookies.

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"test_user", @"username", @"pass", @"password", nil];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/"]];

NSError *error;
NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:0 error:&error];

if ( error ) {
    NSLog( @"ERROR - %@", error.localizedDescription );
} else {
    __block ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request addRequestHeader: @"Content-Type" value:@"application/json; charset=utf-8"]; 
    [request appendPostData:data];
    [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];

    [request setCompletionBlock:^{

        UIAlertView *alerView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login"
                                                           message:@"Login was sent"
                                                          delegate:nil
                                                 cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                                 otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
        [alerView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(show) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

        NSLog(@"RESPONSE: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:request.responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);//, [request.requestCookies objectAtIndex:0]);
        NSLog(@"COOKIE: %@", [request.requestCookies objectAtIndex:0]);
        [ASIHTTPRequest addSessionCookie:[request.requestCookies objectAtIndex:0]];

    }];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I resolved this issue and it turns out that on the server side I was putting in the data but not officially logging in with Django (was not returning the proper cookies) which meant my app was not receiving the proper header.